# Problem with NVIDIA 840M GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have a notebook that has an integrated intel and a dedicated NVIDIA GPU. The problem is that it is only recognizing the intel GPU and every time I install a driver, I can not log in on Ubuntu 15.10. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1 : Remove the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2 : Reinstall the NVIDIA drivers for GEFORCE 840M.**

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password and then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Now you do not have to add the boot parameter anymore when you boot the Ubuntu system.
Don't forget to put a `Space` between the last sign of the linux line and `nouveau.modeset=0`.